# Passport-local-mongoose not working for login after successful signup

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am using passport -local mongoose for authentication. Everytime I am successfully able to signUP the user but when I try to log in with the same id password, wrong username password error pops up
//my signup post request
[image: signup post]
//my signIn request with same credentials
[image]

my schema

```
// userModel.js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import passportLocalMongoose from "passport-local-mongoose";

const { Schema } = mongoose;
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Email is must"],
    unique: true,
    minLength: 2,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: {
      validator: (val) => {
        return /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/i.test(val);
      },
      message: (prop) => `${prop.value} does not match given conditions`,
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    // required: true,
    trim: true,
    minLength: 8,
    maxLength: 15,
    validate: {
      validator: (val) => {
        return /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,15}$/i.test(
          val
        );
      },
      message: (prop) => `${prop.value} doesnot match given condns`,
    },
  },
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField: "email" });
export const Users = mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
```

my config

```
// passport.js
import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from "passport-local";
import { Users } from "../Models/UserModel.js";

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Users.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Users.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Users.deserializeUser());

export default passport;
```

my server.js

```
import passport from "./config/passport.js";
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

my router

```
// authRoutes.js
import express from "express";
import passport from "../config/passport.js";
import { Users } from "../Models/UserModel.js";

const authRouter = express.Router();

authRouter.post("/signIn", function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body.password) {
    res.json({ success: false, message: "Password was not given" });
  } else {
    passport.authenticate("local", function (err, user, info) {
      if (err) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: err });
      } else {
        if (!user) {
          res.json({
            success: false,
            message: "Username or password incorrect",
          });
        } else {
          const token = jwt.sign(
            { userId: user._id, username: user.email },
            secretkey,
            { expiresIn: "24h" }
          );
          res.json({
            success: true,
            message: "Authentication successful",
            token: token,
          });
        }
      }
    })(req, res);
  }
});

authRouter.post("/signUp", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const newUser = new Users({ email });
    await Users.register(newUser, password, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          success: false,
          message: `Your account could not be saved: ${err}`,
        });
      } else {
        req.login(user, (er) => {
          if (er) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: er });
          } else {
            res.json({ success: true, message: "Your account has been saved" });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Error registering user.");
  }
});

authRouter.get("/signOut", (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.send("User logged out.");
});

export default authRouter;
```

How to correct this?